# Why is Flutter NotificationListener not catching my notifications?

Tags: flutter

I am having a problem with the NotificationListener in flutter. I've build a simple testing app because I am struggling with it.

After clicking on the FlatButton the Notification should be dispatched and then caught by the NotificationListener in onNotification.
So the expected console output would be:

"TestNot"

"Bubble"

But all I am getting is "TestNot".

So the notification is not caught by the listener.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thank you :-)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyNotification extends Notification {
  final String title;

  const MyNotification({this.title});
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
     
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
 
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
    
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: NotificationListener<MyNotification>(
          onNotification: (notification) {
            print("Bubble");
            return true;
          },
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
            
              // horizontal).
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                FlatButton(onPressed: () {print("TestNot"); MyNotification(title: "TestNot").dispatch(context);}, child: Text("TestNot")),
                Text(
                  '$_counter',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot receive the notification at the same level of where it was dispatched. Please refer to docs : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html

> NotificationListener class :
> A widget that listens for Notifications bubbling up the tree.

I've updated your code to make it work.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyNotification extends Notification {
      final String title;
    
      const MyNotification({this.title});
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
      final String title;
    
      @override
      _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      int _counter = 0;
    
      void _incrementCounter() {
        setState(() {
          _counter++;
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: NotificationListener<MyNotification>(
              onNotification: (MyNotification notification) {
                print("Bubble");
                return true;
              },
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  // horizontal).
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                    ),            
                    MyChild(),
                    Text(
                      '$_counter',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: _incrementCounter,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
      }
    }
    
    
    class MyChild extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print("TestNot");
          MyNotification(title: "TestNot").dispatch(context);
        },
        child: Text("TestNot"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha, thank you very much! I had falsely interpreted this upward propagation as propagation inside the widget build hierarchy...

Answer (score 3):

When you need a child to notify its parent, you can use [NotificationListener](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NotificationListener-class.html).

[image]

But, when you need communications to be implemented inversely, in other words, a parent to notify its children, you can use [ValueListenableBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html)

[image]

A nice doc about it available here:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-notifications-bubble-up-and-values-go-down-c1a499d22d5f

"Flutter, notifications ‘bubble up’ and values ‘go down’"